# Segmentation fault (core dumped) in fputs()

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I have the following code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    size_t size;
    char *line;

    FILE *pipe = fopen("/ftproot/fifo", "r");

    if(pipe == NULL){
        perror("Could not open pipe for reading");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    FILE *out = fopen("/ftproot/output", "w");

    if(out == NULL){
        perror("Could not open output file for writing");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    while (getline(&line, &size, pipe) > 0) {
        cout << "<<" << line << ">>\n";
        fputs(line, out);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It turns out if I remove the line `cout << "<<" << line << ">>\n";` I receive a Segmentation fault. But, if this line is inside the code everything works fine.

I do not know how this is possible. I would appreciate any answer.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are using an uninitialized pointer, so accessing a random address of memory. That's a shortest way to run into problems...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't set **line** to NULL. Normal local variables initially have garbage in them.

So why does it work when you print the line? The "garbage" in the variable is just what happened to be in the place in memory where the variable is stored, and depending on what else your code does, it can change. This is what the C++ standard calls "undefined behaviour", which means that anything can happen.